# Value assignment on copied object not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript

I have a simple game I'm working through.  At one point I am running some logic to test several possible moves and determine which one gets the best result in the game.  To do this, I am copying the current game state and then trying out a possible move on the new copied state.  When I log the copied game state from the game object everything looks right.  But if I log the copied state from a function on the board object it doesn't look like any values have changed.  What am I missing here?

I have tried using a variety of copy methods including ...spread, JSON Stringify, & Object.assign().

```js
//GameBoard
const Board = () => {
  //gameState keeps track of the possible positions on the game board and who owns them
  let gameState = {
    boardSquare01: "",
    boardSquare02: "",
    boardSquare03: ""
  };

  //calculates the score for the current state of the game.
  function scoreForCurrentState() {
    console.log('GameState as reported from Board: ', gameState);
    return 1000; //just for testing
  }

  return {
    gameState,
    scoreForCurrentState
  };
}

//GameEngine
const Game = (() => {

  let board = null;

  function beginGame(player) {
    board = Board();
    let bestMove = findBestMove();
  }

  //Test each possible move and score it.  Then return the best option.
  function findBestMove() {

    let bestScore = 0;
    let bestPosition = null;

    //search for unclaimed squares
    const availableMoves = Object.keys(board.gameState)
      .filter(gameSquare => board.gameState[gameSquare] === "");

    //iterate through and simulate all available moves
    availableMoves.forEach(move => {
      //copy the current game board to get one we can test a play on
      let newBoard = Board(); //create a new blank board
      //copy the current gameState to the new board
      newBoard.gameState = { ...board.gameState}; 

      newBoard.gameState[move] = "player1"; //record the theoretical play

      console.log('GameState as reported from Game: ', newBoard.gameState);
      //GameState as reported from Game object (as expected):  
      //{boardSquare01: 'player1', boardSquare02: '', boardSquare03: ''}


      const newScore = newBoard.scoreForCurrentState();
      //GameState as reported from Board (not as expected):  
      //{boardSquare01: '', boardSquare02: '', boardSquare03: ''}

      if (bestScore < newScore) {
        bestScore = newScore;
        bestMove = move;
      }
    });

    return bestPosition;
  }

  return {
    beginGame,
  }

})();

Game.beginGame();
```

Comment: Thanks all for the very detailed answers.  Also found the following article on "losing this" helpful: https://javascript.info/bind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

First, on the "not as expected" line, you probably wanted to call `scoreForCurrentState` on `newBoard` instead of `board`.

The second problem is a little bit more complex.

You stored `gameState` inside a closure variable. Then, you assigned it to the returned object's `gameState` property. But there's no correlation between the variable and the property, other than that initially they both point to the same object.

When you replace the state with a new object, you're only changing the property, and leaving the variable point to the old state. And, `scoreForCurrentState` reads the state from the variable, not from the property.

To fix this, you can read from the property by using `this.gameState`, which will work as long as you call it like this:

```
board.scoreForCurrentState()
^^^^^--- That object will become `this`.
```

```js
//GameBoard
const Board = () => {
  //gameState keeps track of the possible positions on the game board and who owns them
  let gameState = {
    boardSquare01: "",
    boardSquare02: "",
    boardSquare03: ""
  };

  //calculates the score for the current state of the game.
  function scoreForCurrentState() {
    console.log('GameState as reported from Board: ', this.gameState);
    return 1000; //just for testing
  }

  return {
    gameState,
    scoreForCurrentState
  };
}

//GameEngine
const Game = (() => {

  let board = null;

  function beginGame(player) {
    board = Board();
    let bestMove = findBestMove();
  }

  //Test each possible move and score it.  Then return the best option.
  function findBestMove() {

    let bestScore = 0;
    let bestPosition = null;

    //search for unclaimed squares
    const availableMoves = Object.keys(board.gameState)
      .filter(gameSquare => board.gameState[gameSquare] === "");

    //iterate through and simulate all available moves
    availableMoves.forEach(move => {
      //copy the current game board to get one we can test a play on
      let newBoard = Board(); //create a new blank board
      newBoard.gameState = { ...board.gameState
      }; //copy the current gameState to the new board
      newBoard.gameState[move] = "player1"; //record the theoretical play

      console.log('GameState as reported from Game: ', newBoard.gameState);
      //GameState as reported from Game object (as expected):  
      //{boardSquare01: 'player1', boardSquare02: '', boardSquare03: ''}


      const newScore = newBoard.scoreForCurrentState();
      //GameState as reported from Board:  
      //{boardSquare01: 'player1', boardSquare02: '', boardSquare03: ''}

      if (bestScore < newScore) {
        bestScore = newScore;
        bestMove = move;
      }
    });

    return bestPosition;
  }

  return {
    beginGame,
  }

})();

Game.beginGame();
```

If you want to bind the `scoreForCurrentState` to an instance of `Board`, you can also store *the object to be returned (`Board` instance)* in a closure variable; that will still allow *the properties of that object* (including `gameState`) to be changed from the outside.

```
const Board = () => {
  const boardInstance = {
  //gameState keeps track of the possible positions on the game board and who owns them
    gameState: {
      boardSquare01: "",
      boardSquare02: "",
      boardSquare03: ""
    },
    scoreForCurrentState
  }

  //calculates the score for the current state of the game.
  function scoreForCurrentState() {
    console.log('GameState as reported from Board: ', boardInstance.gameState);
    return 1000; //just for testing
  }

  return boardInstance
}
```

```js
const Board = () => {
  const boardInstance = {

//gameState keeps track of the possible positions on the game board and who owns them
    gameState: {
      boardSquare01: "",
      boardSquare02: "",
      boardSquare03: ""
    },
    scoreForCurrentState
  }

  //calculates the score for the current state of the game.
  function scoreForCurrentState() {
    console.log('GameState as reported from Board: ', boardInstance.gameState);
    return 1000; //just for testing
  }

  return boardInstance
}

//GameEngine
const Game = (() => {

  let board = null;

  function beginGame(player) {
    board = Board();
    let bestMove = findBestMove();
  }

  //Test each possible move and score it.  Then return the best option.
  function findBestMove() {

    let bestScore = 0;
    let bestPosition = null;

    //search for unclaimed squares
    const availableMoves = Object.keys(board.gameState)
      .filter(gameSquare => board.gameState[gameSquare] === "");

    //iterate through and simulate all available moves
    availableMoves.forEach(move => {
      //copy the current game board to get one we can test a play on
      let newBoard = Board(); //create a new blank board
      newBoard.gameState = { ...board.gameState
      }; //copy the current gameState to the new board
      newBoard.gameState[move] = "player1"; //record the theoretical play

      console.log('GameState as reported from Game: ', newBoard.gameState);
      //GameState as reported from Game object (as expected):  
      //{boardSquare01: 'player1', boardSquare02: '', boardSquare03: ''}


      const newScore = newBoard.scoreForCurrentState();
      //GameState as reported from Board:  
      //{boardSquare01: 'player1', boardSquare02: '', boardSquare03: ''}

      if (bestScore < newScore) {
        bestScore = newScore;
        bestMove = move;
      }
    });

    return bestPosition;
  }

  return {
    beginGame,
  }

})();

Game.beginGame();
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to replace `gameState` after a `Board` has benn created, you could also make your factory function accept an optional initial state argument:

```
const Board = (
  //gameState keeps track of the possible positions on the game board and who owns them
  gameState = {
    boardSquare01: "",
    boardSquare02: "",
    boardSquare03: ""
  }
) => {

  //calculates the score for the current state of the game.
  function scoreForCurrentState() {
    console.log('GameState as reported from Board: ', gameState);
    return 1000; //just for testing
  }

  return {
    gameState,
    scoreForCurrentState
  };
}
```

That way, you could call `Board` like this:

```
const newBoard = Board({...board.gameState})
```

```js
const Board = (
  

//gameState keeps track of the possible positions on the game board and who owns them
  gameState = {
    boardSquare01: "",
    boardSquare02: "",
    boardSquare03: ""
  }
) => {

  //calculates the score for the current state of the game.
  function scoreForCurrentState() {
    console.log('GameState as reported from Board: ', gameState);
    return 1000; //just for testing
  }

  return {
    gameState,
    scoreForCurrentState
  };
}


//GameEngine
const Game = (() => {

  let board = null;

  function beginGame(player) {
    board = Board();
    let bestMove = findBestMove();
  }

  //Test each possible move and score it.  Then return the best option.
  function findBestMove() {

    let bestScore = 0;
    let bestPosition = null;

    //search for unclaimed squares
    const availableMoves = Object.keys(board.gameState)
      .filter(gameSquare => board.gameState[gameSquare] === "");

    //iterate through and simulate all available moves
    availableMoves.forEach(move => {
      //copy the current game board to get one we can test a play on
      let newBoard = Board({ 
        ...board.gameState
      }); //copy the current gameState to the new board)
      newBoard.gameState[move] = "player1"; //record the theoretical play

      console.log('GameState as reported from Game: ', newBoard.gameState);
      //GameState as reported from Game object (as expected):  
      //{boardSquare01: 'player1', boardSquare02: '', boardSquare03: ''}


      const newScore = newBoard.scoreForCurrentState();
      //GameState as reported from Board:  
      //{boardSquare01: 'player1', boardSquare02: '', boardSquare03: ''}

      if (bestScore < newScore) {
        bestScore = newScore;
        bestMove = move;
      }
    });

    return bestPosition;
  }

  return {
    beginGame,
  }

})();

Game.beginGame();
```

Answer (score 0):

`scoreForCurrentState()` doesn't use the `board.gameState` property, it uses the variable `gameState` that's saved in the closure environment. Assigning the property doesn't change that variable.

Change it to use `this.gameState` to access the property.

```js
//GameBoard
const Board = () => {
  //gameState keeps track of the possible positions on the game board and who owns them
  let gameState = {
    boardSquare01: "",
    boardSquare02: "",
    boardSquare03: ""
  };

  //calculates the score for the current state of the game.
  function scoreForCurrentState() {
    console.log('GameState as reported from Board: ', this.gameState);
    return 1000; //just for testing
  }

  return {
    gameState,
    scoreForCurrentState
  };
}

//GameEngine
const Game = (() => {

  let board = null;

  function beginGame(player) {
    board = Board();
    let bestMove = findBestMove();
  }

  //Test each possible move and score it.  Then return the best option.
  function findBestMove() {

    let bestScore = 0;
    let bestPosition = null;

    //search for unclaimed squares
    const availableMoves = Object.keys(board.gameState)
      .filter(gameSquare => board.gameState[gameSquare] === "");

    //iterate through and simulate all available moves
    availableMoves.forEach(move => {
      //copy the current game board to get one we can test a play on
      let newBoard = Board(); //create a new blank board
      newBoard.gameState = { ...board.gameState
      }; //copy the current gameState to the new board
      newBoard.gameState[move] = "player1"; //record the theoretical play

      console.log('GameState as reported from Game: ', newBoard.gameState);
      //GameState as reported from Game object (as expected):  
      //{boardSquare01: 'player1', boardSquare02: '', boardSquare03: ''}


      const newScore = board.scoreForCurrentState();

      if (bestScore < newScore) {
        bestScore = newScore;
        bestMove = move;
      }
    });

    return bestPosition;
  }

  return {
    beginGame,
  }

})();

Game.beginGame();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that objects are reference types, so `newBoard.gameState = { ...board.gameState}` is reassigning `newBoard.gameState`, and will no longer keep a reference to the `gameState` that it was initially pointing to. It is creating a new object each time, and copying the attributes of `board.gameState` before reassigning `newBoard.gameState`.

You instead want to override the attributes of the `newBoard.gameState` with the current board's attributes, which can therefore be accomplished by:

```js
Object.keys(board.gameState).forEach(k => newBoard.gameState[k] = board.gameState[k]);
```

That way you maintain the reference to `gameState` that's already in memory.

You have what I believe is a typo, instead, calculate the `newScore` using `newBoard` by:

```js
const newScore = newBoard.scoreForCurrentState();
```

**Here is the working result**

```js
//GameBoard
const Board = () => {
  //gameState keeps track of the possible positions on the game board and who owns them
  let gameState = {
    boardSquare01: "",
    boardSquare02: "",
    boardSquare03: ""
  };

  //calculates the score for the current state of the game.
  function scoreForCurrentState() {
    console.log('GameState as reported from Board: ', gameState);
    return 1000; //just for testing
  }

  return {
    gameState,
    scoreForCurrentState
  };
}

//GameEngine
const Game = (() => {

  let board = null;

  function beginGame(player) {
    board = Board();
    let bestMove = findBestMove();
  }

  //Test each possible move and score it.  Then return the best option.
  function findBestMove() {

    let bestScore = 0;
    let bestPosition = null;

    //search for unclaimed squares
    const availableMoves = Object.keys(board.gameState)
      .filter(gameSquare => board.gameState[gameSquare] === "");

    //iterate through and simulate all available moves
    availableMoves.forEach(move => {
      //copy the current game board to get one we can test a play on
      let newBoard = Board(); //create a new blank board
      //copy the current gameState to the new board
      Object.keys(board.gameState).forEach(k => newBoard.gameState[k] = board.gameState[k]);

      newBoard.gameState[move] = "player1"; //record the theoretical play

      console.log('GameState as reported from Game: ', newBoard.gameState);
      //GameState as reported from Game object (as expected):  
      //{boardSquare01: 'player1', boardSquare02: '', boardSquare03: ''}


      const newScore = newBoard.scoreForCurrentState();
      //GameState as reported from Board (not as expected):  
      //{boardSquare01: '', boardSquare02: '', boardSquare03: ''}

      if (bestScore < newScore) {
        bestScore = newScore;
        bestMove = move;
      }
    });

    return bestPosition;
  }

  return {
    beginGame,
  }

})();

Game.beginGame();
```

#### Correction

Using the `this` keyword inside `scoreForCurrentState()` would be a better approach as suggested in the other answers.

This is likely a more efficient

[image]

```js
newBoard.gameState = { ...board.gameState };
```

than overriding the individual attributes.

[image]

```js
Object.keys(board.gameState).forEach(k => newBoard.gameState[k] = board.gameState[k]);
```

And you'll still be able to maintain a reference to the initial `gameState` being pointed to from `this.gameState`.

```js
//calculates the score for the current state of the game.
function scoreForCurrentState() {
    console.log('GameState as reported from Board: ', this.gameState);
    return 1000; //just for testing
}
```

I would recommend redefining `Board` to:

```js
class Board {
  constructor(){
    this.gameState = {
      boardSquare01: "",
      boardSquare02: "",
      boardSquare03: ""
    }
  }
  
  //calculates the score for the current state of the game.
  scoreForCurrentState () {
      console.log('GameState as reported from Board: ', this.gameState);
      return 1000; //just for testing
  }
  
  //update the current board
  updateGameState (newState) {
    this.gameState = { ...newState };
    return this;
  }
}
```

This way, `scoreForCurrentState()` will be defined on the prototype, and not instantiated each time a new board gets created.